# How to show \epsilon in R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using R Markdown 1.0.9016 in RStudio 1.0.35 Windows.

I used to be able to render equations like

$\epsilon$

But now it just shows \epsilon instead of rendering the epsilon symbol.

What went wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on the Mac with rmarkdown 1.0.9016 and Rstudio 1.0.36. `$\epsilon$` produces the expected Greek letter as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to need to wrap it in double `$` like `$$\epsilon$$`

Comment: I tried, $\epsilon$, didn't work.

Then i yours $$\epsilon$$ this worked for me. But it produced odd output. The output was as a whole new window. 

However, after I then removed the extra $ and it worked correctly, using $\epsilon$

I suspect there is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it should work:

```
\(\epsilon\)
```